# Notification icon just for senseUI

Tags: android, resources, htcsense

If i follow the user guidelines for the notification bar design it has to be dark gray (for android < 2.3) But on sense, the notification bar is black, so my icon is almost invisible.

Is there a way to detect the senseUI to create a new resources folder just for senseUI ?

Comment: More recent versions of sense allow you to change the colour of the notification bar using skins, which would throw another obstacle in your path ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specifically Sense but you can check the Build strings and match them against known SenseUI phones. `Build.Model` is probably your best bet. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

An alternative would be to let the user change which one gets displayed by placing it in your options screen.

Answer (score 0):

smith324 got to it before I did but here are the relevant Build strings I just pulled of an HTC Desire. Unfortunately no indication of 'Sense' in there but as smith324 suggested, checking against known phones with Sense might help.

```
BOARD: bravo
BRAND: htc_wwe
DEVICE: bravo
HARDWARE: bravo
MANUFACTURER: HTC
MODEL: HTC Desire
PRODUCT: htc_bravo
```